# HighCharts Display Marker Value

Tags: charts, highcharts

Is there any way we can enable highcharts to display marker value at all the times ?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got it working. Posting for reference of others

```
        plotOptions : {
            line : {
                dataLabels : {
                    enabled : true,
                    formatter : function() {
                        return this.y + '%';
                    }
                }
            },
            series : {
                name : 'Team Briefing',
                shadow : false,
                marker : {
                    lineWidth : 2,
                    radius : 6,
                    symbol : 'circle'
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: how to add some text to marker? instead of changing "name" property.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Point Marker](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#point-marker) reference guide. What I remember about Highcharts is that still it does not provide anything such as.

Answer (score 1):

when you initiate the chart with an object (as your first argument) : ' **...new Highcharts.Chart( { ... } )**'
one of this object properties you can use is the **plotOptions.series.marker**

this **marker** is an object itself:

```
 marker:{
           enabled:true,
           lineWith:0.0,
           radius:0.0,
           // more attributes...
        }
```

those are the default setting.  meaning: It is enabled by default, but the radius is also zero by default, and that is the reson you don't see the points .

make a long story short: you need to set the raduis (to be bigger than zero)

read more at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.radius